# Generate java classes with wsdl/xsd files using RAD

Tags: web-services, websphere

I am new to webservice world. I just got WSDL and XSD files from another Interface Application and want to start from here. Can anyone please help with the steps or tutorial to generate java classes with available wsdl and xsd files using RAD?

Answer (score 1):

Two walkthrus for this process

[IBM's docs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_yee/0803_yee.html)

OR you can try this [Websphere docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.webservice.was.creation.core.doc/ref/rwsdl2client.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of resources. YOu got to state the version of RAD that you are using. Redbooks are a good source for such information besides the Infocenter.

This approach that you are looking at is called a Top-Down Process where in you start with the WSDLs & XSDs and create the service implementation.

Try this one: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247672.html

Look at chapter 18 Developing Web services applications and you should be looking at "Creating a top-down Web service from a WSDL"

HTH