# IBM RAD / RSA: "Generate Java bean skeleton" Does Not Display When Right-Clicking WSDL File

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, rational-rsa

Using IBM Rational Software Architect 9.5 for Windows, I am working through a tutorial for a top-down (contract-first) SOAP Web Service from a WSDL, as described in this IBM Redbook:

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247672.pdf (which had been recommended in this Stack Overflow post: [Generate java classes with wsdl/xsd files using RAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016813/generate-java-classes-with-wsdl-xsd-files-using-rad))

I have a WSDL file, and I'm supposed to right-click this file, and choose, from the context menu, "Web Services -> Generate Java bean skeleton".

For whatever reason, the only sub-menu under "Web Services" is "Test With Generic Service Client".

What might I be doing incorrectly, and what should I do at this point in order to generate skeleton classes from this WSDL?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.

When using RSA 9.5's wizard for creating a Dynamic Web Project for the Web Service, I had been selecting *Dynamic web module version* 3.0.

When I instead selected *Dynamic web module version* 2.5, right-clicking the WSDL file and choosing "Web Services" from the context menu did indeed display the "Generate Java bean skeleton".

I don't know why selection *Dynamic web module version* 3.0 prevents this menu item from displaying. I assume that the old "Generate Java bean skeleton" option has been replaced by something else, but I don't know what at this time.